# How do I add a class attribute to my Html.Textbox or other form vallue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, attributes

how do I add a class attribute if I already have an ID attribute?
The compiler keeps screaming ratial epitets at me...

Html.TextBox("", "", new {id = nodes["id"].Value class = ?????}))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you capitalise the c in class it will work

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prop, new {Class="class"})
```

As Mystere says, this is because class is a reserved word.

When your aspx page gets transformed into html the attribute will be lowercased

Answer (score 2):

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Thing, new {@class="myclass"})
```

The @ is needed, probably because class is a reserved word in C#